# AS3 unload external file when clicking another button

Tags: actionscript-3, button, load, external

I'm loading this txt-file in AS3 (Flash) with a button click. But I want the txt to disappear when I click any other button. I tried stop(); and unloadAndStop, but it don't work. Any ideas?

```
hello_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  buttonClick4)
function  buttonClick4(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     try{
loader_mc.unloadAndStop();
} catch(e:Error) {
}
      var loader:URLLoader;
var info_text:TextField;

CSSFormattingExample();

function CSSFormattingExample():void
{
    info_text = new TextField();
    info_text.wordWrap = true;
    info_text.x = 300;
    info_text.y = 160;
    info_text.width = 800;
    info_text.height = 800;
    addChild(info_text);
}
var url:String = "hello.txt";
var loadit:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loadit.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loadit.load(new URLRequest(url));

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    info_text.htmlText = event.target.data as String;
}
}
```

Comment: You first have to `removeChild()` that SWF, otherwise you can't unload and stop.

Comment: @Vesper Ok, but where should I put that? Anywhere I put it I get errors.

Comment: You know what? It's possible you have already lost the valid link to `loader_mc`, as I see your code having two other loaders already. Also, what are the errors? You should put `removeChild()` call right before `unloadAndStop()` call of yours, inside `try-catch` block, and trace those errors if you receive them.

Comment: Yep, you load a text and want it to disappear? The text is not a MovieClip, you don't need to unload and stop that, you just invalidate links and change the displayed text to unload it.

Comment: @Vesper And how can I do that?

Comment: `info_text.htmlText=''` that's all.